# Check url if exists with command prompt for Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

```
@echo off & setlocal

:start
set ser=mywebsite.com

echo Checking WEB site by^
 pinging %ser%

  set ok_=true
  ping -n 1 %ser%|find "Lost = 0">nul||set ok_=
  if defined ok_ (
    echo "urlok."
    ) else (
    echo "urlnotok."
    )
pause>nul

endlocal
```

I have this code. if i ping main url (domain), Its working. 
But it does not work 
**if i ping:**

> mywebsite.com/foldername

How can i get "urlok" result with pinging folder, also I can use checking "url with folder" it does not matter if i ping website or not
**I am trying to check url if exits or not.**

Comment: Please do not spam irrelevant tags. This question has nothing at all to do with c or c++.

Comment: I can use c++ and c with system(commands)
so i can check url with c++ or c.
Program language does not matter for me. I only want to check website url with folder if exists or not.